# Problemas na comunicação serial com python

Tags: python, serial, usb

Então, estou desenvolvendo um projeto para universidade, é basicamente o desenvolvimento de um supervisório. Tenho que fazer a leitura de alguns módulos I/O que se comunicam através de uma rede RS485.
A comunicação com o módulo principal se dá através da comunicação serial, mas estou com problemas nessa leitura.
Utilizando o pacote serial, em python, realizo a leitura da seguinte forma:

```
response = bytearray()
print("Sending " + cmd)

ser.open()

if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        ser.reset_input_buffer()

# Envia os dados e recebe a resposta
if ser.isOpen():
    ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
    time.sleep(SLEEP_VALUE)
    while ser.inWaiting() == 0:
        ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
        time.sleep(SLEEP_VALUE)

    response.extend(ser.read((BIGGEST_N_OUTPUT * 8) + 2))  # Leitura de até 8 sinais + '>'
else:
    print("ERRO DE CONEXAO COM PORTA SERIAL")
```

Onde "cmd" é a variável que contém os códigos a serem enviados para o módulo. Ao final dele existe uma quebra de linha (conforme solicitado pelo manual de fabricante do módulo):

```
# Comando a ser escrito
cmd = '#' + str(ID) + str(channel) + '\r\n'
```

Este trecho de código fica em um eventual loop para realizar diversas leituras sequenciais. Acontece que, em algumas escritas aleatórias, ao utilizar o comando ser.Write, não recebo nenhuma resposta do módulo, resultando em um buffer de entrada (ser.inWaiting) igual a zero. Por este motivo escrevi o loop while para que o programa tente fiar escrevendo repetidamente até se obter uma resposta.

Existe alguma forma melhor de realizar as leituras? Já tentei mudar o tempo de timeout, ou mesmo acrescentar um valor maior de pausa no time.sleep(), porém mesmo com uma pausa muito grande o resultado é o mesmo. Também reseto o buffer antes de cada leitura, para assegurar a ausência de demais erros.

Comment: Se você já consegiu trocar dados com a serial, já é meio caminho andado.

Provavelmente você está mandando dados sem um final  de linha, e o dado fica "preso" esperando um "newline" ou fechar a conexão para ser enviado. Se for isso, depois de cada escrita, e antes do "sleep", chame o método "flush" da porta: `ser.flush()` .

Comment: Uma outra dica antes de avançar no seu projeto: espero que você tenha entendido como funcionam funções e faça bastante uso delas Deixar codigo de comunicação espalhado pelo módulo como está nesse exemplo é uma péssima prática e será um fator de bloqueio para você desenvolver o projeto.  Se ainda não fez, aproveite para estudar essa parte criando vários exemplos.

Comment: @jsbueno O comando `ser.flush()` diminuiu a quantidade de erros de leitura/escrita, mas eles continuam acontecendo. Não sei se o final de linha comentado seria uma quebra de linha de fato. A pergunta foi atualizada. Mas de qualquer forma ajudou bastante.

Comment: acho que não da pra responder mais que isso - mesmo que você melhore o código da pergunta, colocando um exemplo completo e verificável, sem estar experimentando junto.

Comment: Tente melhorar o código na questão: ponha uma listagem completa do programa, pelo menos escrevendo e lendo uma mensagem - de forma que se alguém estivesse com seu dispositivo aqui, poderia copiar e colar seu código e rodar.
Pode ter a ver com uso cruzado da interface, entre outras coisas.